# Prevent auto-saving collections in EF XAF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aggregate, xaf

In Entity Framework XAF project, I am using aggregated attribute for many to one relationships [DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.Aggregated]. The parent object is A, and the child one is B.

When I add new B object or edit it, it is automatically saved without the need to save the parent (A) to let it be saved. How to prevent this behavior and prevent the child object (B) to be saved unless the parent is saved.